# magento 2 jquery in minTime and maxTime is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, magento, magento2

```
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function ($) {
       
 $(document).ready(function () {
            
$('#myTimePicker').timepicker({
             
   minTime: '09:00 AM', 
             
   maxTime: '05:00 PM', 
            
    timeFormat: 'h:mm TT'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my code. in this code minTime and maxTime is not working.
I have try to min only, am and pm small case, i want to show time 9am to 5pm only

Ans minTime replace with hourMin

Comment: minTime: '09:00',  maxTime: '17:00', have you try 24-time format?